# owl carousel no working in IE8 and IE9

Tags: jquery, plugins, owl-carousel

I'm using owl-carousel responsive plugin for my website. 
But i got a problem with this when open in internet explorer.
Does anyone know how to run owl-carousel plugin in IE8 AND IE9?

Comment: This [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hooj7vd8/27/) works in IE9..

Comment: Just try it yourself..?

Comment: cuz,,, my one is not working

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I had the same problem, a console.log() i had was bugging it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is jQuery version, Owl carousel will not work with jQuery version 1.10. So you need to downgrade jQuery version to 1.9.1. [`Working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/6d2cK/63/)